# How to keep one column fixed with no scroll and another one normal with scroll?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have two divs side by side in my website. I want to make one of the divs fixed with no scroll and the other one normal with scroll. How to do that? Here is a picture for better understanding.[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8tHd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstraps overflow-classes.

Documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/overflow/

```
<div class="overflow-auto">...</div>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/kzh9bp24/9/

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done with pure css

For this to work, you have to make sure that you add a ***max-height*** and ***overflow-y: auto*** to your div.

```css
.scrollDiv{
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
  
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="scrollDiv">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae molestie eros. Vestibulum id elementum leo, eu venenatis felis. Nam vitae nisi dignissim, pellentesque purus ut, mattis sem. Duis vestibulum, sem pellentesque pharetra interdum, turpis ex aliquam augue, quis ornare tortor felis eu turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed vitae lorem sodales, blandit mi vitae, sollicitudin mauris. Praesent a ex et leo commodo tincidunt ut id mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Integer maximus tortor ante, vel posuere tortor tristique quis.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```